# Upload file to gcp storage in order to route the traffic through gcp interconnect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

when we are connecting from our on prem server to our gcs bucket and we use gsutil and the gsutil has the google API, if that’s get called the domain server give us the public IP and that public IP is not same our interconnect IP, so the traffic will not route through the interconnect. In that case how we can get the static IP from cloud DNS in order to route the traffic through interconnect
Service info in Brief:
we use Microservice for uploading file via gsutil tool to GCS storage.

- DNS: storage.googleapis.com
- gsutil doing dns lookup before connecting to google the api.
- Connection: HTTPs
  Now if we connect our on prem sever to cloud storage through f5 to upload a file we need same IP to route the traffic through interconnect. But when I ping storage.googleapis.com I am getting public IP which is not same our interconnect IP